# how to print out more than a character at once

Tags: c++

I saved this word "abs" in a text file and i'm trying to make a code that can print the three characters at once in another file .. not like that

```
while (content[i] == 'a')
{
fout<<"a";
break;}
while (content[i] == 'b')
{
fout<<"b";
break;}
while (content[i] == 's')
{
fout<<"s";
break;}
```

here is the code i wrote but it doesn't print anything out..

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
ofstream fout("E:\\hoss.txt");
ifstream file("E:\\test.txt");
string content;
while(file >> content)
{
for (size_t i = 0; i < content.size(); i++)
{
while (content[i] == 'ab')
{
fout<<"ab";
break;}
}}
system("pause");
return  0;
}
```

anyone can help??

Comment: 'ab' is string here not character.(content[i] == 'ab') how can two characters can be found on same index [i]??

Comment: you can use like this if((content[i] == 'a') && (content[i+1] == 'b'))

Comment: great, have fun...!!!

Comment: I'm putting it as final solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int main()
{
ofstream fout("E:\\hoss.txt");
ifstream file("E:\\test.txt");
string content;
while(file >> content)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < content.size(); i++)
    {
        if((content[i] == 'a') && (content[i+1] == 'b'))
        {
           fout<<"ab";
           break;
        }
    }
}
system("pause");
return  0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have no code to print anything out. You just keep adding to the buffer, but you never flush the buffer. Get rid of the `system("pause");` and just let the program end. Ending the program flushes all buffers.

```
while (content[i] == 'ab')
```

This is pretty baffling. Did you really mean `ab` as a character constant?

Comment: the system("pause");  is because i'm using Dev-C++ and i have to write it or i won't see any outputs ... and please give me an example for what you mean because i'm pretty new to c++ ..thank you

Comment: @user3487485 You don't have to write it. Just run your program from a terminal. Don't bastardize your code to work in a broken environment. That will cause bugs *just like this one*.